# Codeigniter remove specific user's session

Tags: codeigniter

In Codeigniter, how do I remove specific user's session?

I have set login session like below. And I want to remove specific MemId's LoggedIn(in other words, session for just one user) assuming there are about 1000 users.

```
$this->session->set_userdata([
    'LoggedIn'=>true,'MemId'=>PrimaryKey
]);
```

Comment: Do you save the session MemId in database? What is PrimaryKey?

Answer (score -1):

When user logged in you are setting two session variables.One is `LoggedIn` and another 'MemId' which is the primary key of member.So,first retrieve the logged in user `member id` from database then unset it.Might work properly.

`MemId` is the member id of user for which you want to remove session.

```
 $this->session->unset_userdata('MemId');
```